# El Capitan Notes creates auto list items when I type '-' dash

Tags: osx-elcapitan

Before El Capitan, I used to be able to disable the smart text functionality on mac notes by unchecking the smart features that i didnt like. ex.:

[image]

It seems this doesnt matter anymore. I have disabled the Smart Dashes, but still Notes creates a list item whenever I type '-'.

Is this a bug? 
Can I, and if yes, how can I disable auto-list-item creation when I type '-'?

Comment: Same thing for me... "Smart Lists" option is greyed out, also in El Capitan.